# How to make background transparent in android

Tags: android, overlay, android-canvas, transparent, bitmapimage

I have two images in drawable folder and I am doing this:

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image2);


canvas.drawBitmap(background,0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(image, x, y, null);
```

There is WHITE background in my picture named "image" but i want to show only the object of that picture means want to make the background transparent.
How can I do this ?

Comment: How about you draw the drawable image itself to have that transparent background?

Comment: Yeah, finally worked with transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the canvas transparent before drawing the images.

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the Transparent color as a background, which is set the same as any drawable, just use `@android:color/transparent`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage"
    android:alpha=".75"/>
Programatically, you can also set it with

int alphaAmount = 125; // some value 0-255 where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque
myImage.setAlpha(alphaAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent `drawable` and make it as the background of the `View` .

Android uses Hex ARGB values, which are formatted as #AARRGGBB. That first pair of letters, the AA, represent the Alpha Channel. To set alpha value you must convert your decimal opacity values to a Hexdecimal value.

**Here's hex Opacity Values**

- 100% — FF
- 95% — F2
- 90% — E6
- 85% — D9
- 80% — CC
- 75% — BF
- 70% — B3
- 65% — A6
- 60% — 99
- 55% — 8C
- 50% — 80
- 45% — 73
- 40% — 66
- 35% — 59
- 30% — 4D
- 25% — 40
- 20% — 33
- 15% — 26
- 10% — 1A
- 5% — 0D
- 0% — 00

Answer (score 0):

If your image has white background then you can use setAlpha() for drawable.
But the best way is that you should use image with no background.

Example :

```
 imageview.getDrawable().setAlpha(60);
```